# Link and Select dropdown in one wrapper causing not able to select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react js. Here I have following code where. ,

```
 <Link to='/test/1'>
     <div>
         // Here I have my select component as well  
    </div>     
 </Link>
```

Now, When I am trying to select that element from the dropdown that time, not able to because it is getting navigated because of the `Link`. So, How do I make that to select even if there is a link ,
and that select has to be in the Link tag as it is a wrapper for that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture click events on the select and prevent their default action:

```js
<Link to='/test/1'>
     <div>
         <select onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
           <option>something</option>
         </select>
    </div>     
</Link>
```

This prevents the click event from opening the link.

If you wanted to generalize this so that it works on a few different elements inside your Link, you could create a wrapper component:

```js
export const PreventDefaultClick = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```js
<Link to='/test/1'>
  <div>
    <PreventDefaultClick>
      <select>
        <option>something</option>
      </select>
    </PreventDefaultClick>
  </div>     
</Link>
```

Here's some working code:

```js
const PreventDefaultClick = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <a href='https://example.com'>
      <PreventDefaultClick>
        <select>
          <option>one</option>
          <option>two</option>
        </select>
      </PreventDefaultClick>
      <p>clicking here will still open the link</p>
    </a>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
</div>
```

Comment: Now it can open that select but still calls the Link. it is not the immediate children but there is not event for in between eleemnts

Comment: @ganeshk Oops, I called the wrong function on the event. Should have used `preventDefault`. I updated my answer.